# C#でVisioのレイヤーをすべて有効にし、すべてのシェイプを表示させたい

Tags: c#, visio

C#でVisioの操作をしています。
VisioのC#によるコードはあまり情報がなく、VBAのコードを真似て書いています。

やりたいことは「すべてのレイヤーをアクティブにしてすべてのシェイプを表示したい」です。
下記コードですべてのレイヤーのVisibleをTrueにすることは確認できました。

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio;

Document doc = app.Documents.OpenEx(f, (short)VisOpenSaveArgs.visOpenMacrosDisabled);
Page page = doc.Pages[1];

foreach(Layer layer in  page.Layers)
{
  //すべてのレイヤーのVisibleをTrueにする。
  layer.CellsC[((short)VisCellIndices.visLayerVisible)].FormulaU = "1";
}
　
doc.Save();
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

しかし、もともと非表示にしていたレイヤーに属するシェイプは、実際には表示されず、かつ消えています。
上記コードではレイヤーを有効にしてシェイプを表示することはできないのでしょうか。

Comment: この辺の記事が何か参考になるかもしれません。[Kline-/visio_toggle.vba](https://gist.github.com/Kline-/cdde62c2c1ca1a38acf7179bca24c5fe), [VBA: For Each Shape in Specific Layers](http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=3488.0), [Select Sub/Super Shapes via VBA and assign them to a Layer](http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=9066.0), [How To Show Or Hide All Objects (Pictures/Charts/Shapes/Comments) In Excel?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1179-excel-show-hide-objects.html)

Comment: 情報提供ありがとうございます。上記リンクの通り、VBAで書くとうまくいきますが、C#だとレイヤーにチェックは入るのに、そのレイヤーに属するShapeが非表示のままです…